# Azure search highlight not working if the sentence has special character

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Team,
I am using below sample azure search query

```
`{azuresearchurl}/docs?api-version=2019-05-06?search=examples&highlight=title&$select=title
```

I am getting below response.

```
      "@search.highlights": {
      "title": [
         ": From <em>Examples</em> of our Projects"
         ]
        },
        "title": "Can we execute? : From Examples of our Projects"
        }
```

In the above result, we can see text before '?' not added in highlight field value.
How to fix this issue. in highlight field I need to get same text which is available in search result field.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The text before the '?' is "execute", not "exemple". Is this a typo?

Comment: Yes it is execute. "Can we execute?" not added in highlight

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The highlight feature only returns the fragment of text where the searched term is found. Those fragments are generated by finding sentence boundaries. In this case, the interrogation mark indicates the end of a different sentence, so it's not included in the fragment.

Comment: Thanks ramero, is there any option to include entire text as single sentence (without considering special characters)?